# Allowed memory size exhausted in PHP

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I have following code to fetch all details of question time and answers:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('education/hub/kautilya/connection.php');

    function getAllAnswersAndTime($papId)
    {
        $c=new Connection;
        $conn=$c->getConnection();
        $date=date("Y-m-d");        
        $sql="select GROUP_CONCAT(`all_time_questions`) as `time`, GROUP_CONCAT(`all_answers`) as `answers` from `result` where `paper_id` = '$papId'";
        $record=$conn->query($sql);
        return $record;

    }
$papId = $_REQUEST['papId'];
$resall = getAllAnswersAndTime($papId);
$alltime = "";
$allans = "";


function multiexplode ($delimiters,$data) {
    $MakeReady = str_replace($delimiters, $delimiters[0], $data);
    $Return    = explode($delimiters[0], $MakeReady);
    return  $Return;
}


$totalCandidates = 0;
foreach($resall as $row)
{
    $totalCandidates +=1 ;
    $alltime = $row['time'];
    $allans = $row['answers'];
}
unset($resall);
$alltime = ltrim($alltime, "::");
$all_time = multiexplode(array("::","=>"), $alltime);
$all_ans = multiexplode(array("::","=>"), $allans);
$total = 0;
$total_times = [];
$total_ans = [];
for($i = 0; $i < count($all_time); $i+=1)
{
    if($i%2==1)
    {
        $total_times[$all_time[$i-1]] += $all_time[$i];
        $total_ans[$all_time[$i-1]] = 0;
    }
}


for($i = 0; $i < count($total_times); $i+=1)
{
    $total_times[$i] /= $totalCandidates;
}
for($i = 0; $i < count($all_ans); $i+=1)
{
    if($i%2==1)
    {
        $total_ans[$all_ans[$i-1]] += 1;
    }
}

for($i = 0; $i < count($total_ans); $i+=1)
{
    $total_ans[$i] /= $totalCandidates;
    $total_ans[$i] *= 100;
}

$cc['tot_ans'] = $total_ans;
$cc['tot_time'] = $total_times;
echo json_encode($cc);
?>
```

I am getting an error of Allowed memory size exhausted in error_log. I have read the other questions and tried both setting the `memory_limit=2048M` and optimized the query so that it returns concatenated strings, but it doesn't seem to resolve the problem. Can someone please tell me how to solve this?

Also the data is not big at all, it is just two rows with about 20 entries as a result in the arrays.

Comment: after setting the value in php.ini you need to restart the apache server

Comment: I am running on cpanel.. the exceeded value limit increments everytime I change php.ini.. i.e when I set it to 320M, it says "Allowed memory size of 335544320 bytes exhausted".. when I set it to 512 it says "Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted"

Comment: better you increase the memory limit for your function from your code using ini_set() function

Comment: sorry, but if it's a class shoul'nt you use $rec = new Record() ; instead of $rec = new Record ?

Comment: That said, it's using a lot of memory, it may depends on the Record.php object and class functionality. ;)

Comment: @Goikiu I removed the record file and wrote the functionality directly into the code, but still it is giving the same error..

Comment: and this does not change OP, you should SEE what the code of record.php do, not where is written :|

Comment: @Goikiu Updated the code.. please take a look.

Comment: okay, you should rethink your approach, as far as i know working so much on string on php isn't really so easy. (as in a lot of languages), why you do not do a real optimized query on the db? The code does not have comments, so we cannot even help you on reaching more easily your goal ;)

Comment: Often, what I'll do is comment out chunks of code until it runs.  Then reintroduce the code to determine what specific section is causing the problem.  You may even be able to get it down to a single line.  Then you'll know exactly what to optimize or correct.